Trouble running gazebo simulation on ROS2 Humble
Here is what my Launch file looks like:
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
return LaunchDescription([
    Node(
        package='gazebo_ros_pkgs',
        executable='gazebo',
        name='gazebo',
        output='screen'
    ),
    Node(
        package='gazebo_ros_pkgs',
        executable='spawn_entity.py',
        name='spawn_urdf',
        output='screen',
        arguments=['-entity mower', '-file $(arg robot_description)', '-x 0', '-y 0', '-z 0']
    ),
    Node(
        package='mower_sim',
        executable='bcd_node',
        name='bcd_node',
        output='screen'
    )
])

and here is my .urdf file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="prism">

<!-- Base link of the robot -->
<link name="base_link">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.2 0.2 0.2"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="red">
            <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
        </material>
    </visual>
</link>

<!-- Joint to connect the base_link to the world -->
<joint name="world_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="base_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

Here is the error that I receive:
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): Caught exception when trying to load file of format [launch]: Attribute exec of type <class 'str'> not found in Entity node

In addition, when I comment out the first node, I get this error:
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): package 'mower_sim' found at '/home/name/mower_sim_ws/install/mower_sim', but libexec directory '/home/name/mower_sim_ws/install/mower_sim/lib/mower_sim' does not exist


try replacing gazebo_ros_pkgs with gazebo_ros. I think this is just a syntax problem.
